# Fivestar: How to display description text inline

Tags: rating

By default, the Fivestar module offers (at Structure » Content types » Article » Manage Display » Fivestar settings) to show "Text to display **under** the stars". It looks then like this:

[image]

How to show the description text **inline beside** the stars?

I wasn't able to do that in CSS (or to find the caused code in the module).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's doable with CSS. You need to declare the parent of the description and the stars as flex or inline-flex or -webkit-inline-box: .field-type-fivestar .form-item { display: -webkit-inline-box; }